# Создание выпадающего меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Есть выпадающее меню со структурой Родитель > Ребенок уровень-1 > Ребенок уровень-2. Блоки-подменю не являются его непосредственными потомками (соседние дивы):

`<div class="menu">ul,li</div>
<div class="sub-menu-1">ul,li</div><div class="sub-menu-2">ul,li</div>`

Показ подменю 1 уровня происходит при клике на соответствующий пункт меню-родителя, поэтому описать событие не представляет трудностей

`$('.menu li').click(...)`

Проблема состоит в том, что меню 2 уровня должно показываться при ховере на соответствующий элемент первого подменю. Я никак не могу правильно подобрать события, с которыми показ-скрытие подменю-2 происходит адекватно. 
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: `родитель:hover + соседний_элемент {display: block;} соседний_элемент:hover {display: block;}`

Comment: Покажите рабочий пример меню

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой способ. Используем событие `hover`, но скрываем подменю с небольшой задержкой. Это нужно для того, чтобы за это время сработало событие `hover` у самого подменю и заблокировало скрытие, если нужно.

```js
$('.menu li, .submenu').hover(function() {
  // определяем подменю
  var $menu = $(this)
  if (!$(this).hasClass("submenu")) {
    $menu = $('.' + $(this).data("sub"))
  }
  // ставим флаг "в фокусе"
  $menu.data('infocus', 1 );
  // показываем активное подменю
  $menu.show().siblings('.submenu').hide();
  
}, function() {

 // определяем подменю
  var $menu = $(this)
  if (!$(this).hasClass("submenu")) {
    $menu = $('.' + $(this).data("sub"))
  }
  // ставим флаг "не в фокусе"
  $menu.data('infocus', 0);
  // скрываем активное подменю, с небольшой задержкой
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($menu.data('infocus') == 0) $menu.hide();
  }, 10)

})
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
   background:#eee;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class=menu>
  <li data-sub="submenu1">submenu1</li>
  <li data-sub="submenu2">submenu2</li>
</ul>

<div class="submenu submenu1">submenu1</div>
<div class="submenu submenu2">submenu2</div>
```